# How to ge the nearby locations from my GPS coordinates?

Tags: android, sql-server, gps

i got the location from the android GPS and it seems like it is giving me this format
DD.dddddd
which i think is called the decimal format?

now i have Latitude and Longitude. i want to find all the nearby locations that are 200 Meters away.

how can i Calculate this so i can query the SQL Server database for any location that is close to me by 200 Meters?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to give a look at [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) presentation, as shown on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639021/fast-retrieval-of-select-statement-with-gps-coordinates-in-mysql) previous SO post.